# NGINX reverse proxy not forwarding the request hostname to docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, hostname

#### Problem:

We've setup a docker container running on port `3002` and then configured port `3002` to `/path/` on my domain `www.example.com`. There's an express rest api is running on `3002` port container which outputs the `req.hostname` and when I make a request from let's say `www.abc.com`, the consoled value of `req.hostname` is shown to be `www.example.com` instead of `www.abc.com`.

Nginx Conf

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/__abc.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/abc.key;

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    location  / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
    location /path/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }
}
```

What changes do I have to make so I can get the `www.abc.com` in consoled value?

Answer (score 1):

Nginx's `location` blocks should be ordered such that **more specific expressions come first**.

In your example, you should have:

```
    location /path/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3002/;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    location  / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
```

Make sure your changes take effect by either running `nginx -s reload` or restarting the container